# Iterate over hash keys and find associated records based on attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Sorry for the horrible question title. What i'm trying to find is; is there a better way that uses less ruby and more ActiveRecord/SQL to do the same thing?

```
Job.level_count.keys[0..2].map do |loi|
    job_company_id = Job.find_by(level_of_interest: loi).company_id
    Company.find(job_company_id)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#joins` and join `Company` with `Job` and then query on `jobs.level_of_interest`. Your iteration can be substituted with single query like this

```
Company.joins(:jobs)
       .where('jobs.level_of_interest in (?)', Job.level_count.keys[0..2])
#=> SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` INNER JOIN `jobs` ON `jobs`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` WHERE (jobs.level_of_interest in (5, 3, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Company.joins(:jobs).where(jobs: { level_of_interest: [ array, of, loi, values] }).uniq
```

Comment: Thank you! Still getting used to the `.joins`

Comment: Yw, I always need to double check before using them